# Shortcut to select themove the cursor to some time

Tags: adobe-after-effects, shortcuts

I just want a shortcut to focus on this cursor timer

[image: time display for cursor]

Like this!!

[image]

So that I don't have to all the way to that corner and click then type the cursor time... is there any shortcut for it??

Answer (score 1):

When in the *Timeline Panel* (hit <kbd>\</kbd> to switch) you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> and then enter in your desired time and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl + shift + j</kbd>  helps to open the go to time feature.

I changed it <kbd>Q</kbd> by pressing <kbd>alt + shift + '</kbd> and then in the search bar type ***alt+shift+'*** you just choose that option and click on <kbd>Q</kbd>

I found out about this [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/in/after-effects/using/keyboard-shortcuts-reference.html#time_navigation_keyboard_shortcuts)!!